# How does Node's require() resolve, such that persisted database pooling in Express works?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I feel that I am lacking some basic understanding of how nodejs' architecture is put together so that the code below runs with no problems. I'm going to lay out a simple app. Can you guys help me with the questions at the end?

Notes:
I am using the mysql package https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

`node app.js` is run from the command line.

Inside `app.js` is this:

```
const Express = require("express");
const Path = require("path");

const app = Express();  

// Require controller modules
var book_controller = require('../controllers/bookController');
var author_controller = require('../controllers/authorController');

router.get('/book', book_controller.books_get);
router.get('/author', book_controller.authors_get);

app.listen(5000, function(){
    console.log("Server started on port 5000");
});
```

Inside `bookController`:

```
var getConnection = require('../config/mysql');

// Display list of all books
exports.book_get = function(req, res) {
    getConnection(function(err, con) {
        query = 'SELECT * FROM books';
        con.query(query, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            con.release();
            res.render('page/authors', { result:result});
        });
    })        
};
```

Inside `authorController`:

```
var getConnection = require('../config/mysql');

// Display list of all books
exports.authors_get = function(req, res) {       
    getConnection(function(err, con) {
        query = 'SELECT * FROM authors';
        con.query(query, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            con.release();
            res.render('page/books', { result:result});
        });
    })      
};
```

Inside `mysql.js`

```
var mysql = require('mysql');    
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    connectTimeout: 5000,
    acquireTimeout: 5000,
    queueLimit: 30,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '',
    password: '',
    database: '',
    multipleStatements: true,
});    

var getConnection = function(callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(err, connection);
    });
};

pool.on('acquire', function(connection) {
    console.log('Connection %d acquired', connection.threadId);
});
module.exports = getConnection;
```

That's the layout. Here are the questions:

1. How do separate files requiring the same dependency interact? Books and Author controllers both need to require and access the mysql pool, assumedly from different users. Is a new copy of the MySQL object instantiated?
2. How does the state from the pool persist to the next connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do separately required files interact? Books and Author controllers both need to require and access the mysql pool, assumedly from different users. Is a new copy of the MySQL object instantiated?

No, a new copy of the object will not be created on every call to `require`.

In Node, modules are loaded as needed and the resulting export object is **cached** for subsequent calls to `require`, so you'll get the exact same reference to `getConnection` every time you call `require('../config/mysql')`. The lines before `module.exports = getConnection;` run *only* the first time that the module is required.

> How does the state from the pool persist to the next connection?

Because the exported `getConnection` is cached, that function will always refer to the same `pool` object, so both of your controllers are referring to the same pool.